# Measure the content area of an element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can you get the dimensions of the content area of a DOM element?

Strangely couldn't find a question/answer to this. Many questions about measuring DOM elements as a whole, but none about the content area itself.

**Example:**

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;

  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  margin: 15px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now somethings get you various parts of the box model, but nothing seems to give you the content:

```
const elem = document.querySelector('div');

elem.offsetWidth; // content + padding + border
elem.clientWidth; // content + padding

window.getComputedStyle(elem); // Returns an object with width padding and border as strings like "15px".

window.getBoundingClientRect(); // Gives width and height of total box-model excluding margin if sizing is border-box.
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to subtract the computed paddings from the client width and height:

```js
const elem = document.getElementById('elem');

const computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(elem)

const extraWidthOffset =  +computedStyles.getPropertyValue("padding-left").slice(0, -2) + +computedStyles.getPropertyValue("padding-right").slice(0, -2)

const extraHeightOffset =  +computedStyles.getPropertyValue("padding-top").slice(0, -2) + +computedStyles.getPropertyValue("padding-bottom").slice(0, -2)

const contentWidth = elem.clientWidth - extraWidthOffset
const contentHeight = elem.clientWidth - extraHeightOffset

console.log(contentWidth, contentHeight)
```

```css
#elem {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;

  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px;
  margin: 15px;

  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="elem">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any reason for using offsetWidth instead of clientWidth? That way you can skip subtracting the margins.

Comment: Also, will the computed properties always be in pixels, or can they be in other units which will throw off the slice here?

Comment: @DonP the unit returned is always in pixels.

Comment: @DonP Using `clientWidth` is indeed a better approach. I've updated my answer to use it.